# Is there another way to refactor after adding new column: Sinatra Web App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, sinatra

I am still new to using the Sinatra Framework. I was asked to add a new column `:description`, and to refactor this current line of code in my  POST request for editing a new list to include the `:description` column:           `@list.update(params.select{|k|k== "name"})`

I am unsure of not only refactoring it to include the `:description` but to make it shorter.

Here is the full POST request block

```
post "/lists/:id" do
  redirect_if_not_logged_in
  @list = List.find(params[:id])
  unless List.valid_params?(params)
    redirect "/lists/#{@list.id}/edit?error=invalid list"
  end
  @list.update(params.select{|k|k== "name"})
  redirect "/lists/#{@list.id}"
end
```

I did add the new column without issue and have an idea of what to put in my `Edit` & `New` forms, the controller action is where I am stuck.

Comment: I'm a little hazy on the aim. Do you mean you want to update 2 fields, `name` and `description` when posting to this route?

Comment: Hi iain! Yes, sorry. I tend to make things sound and be more complicated than they need to be. After much screen-staring, and help from a friend, I realized I just need to change my current line to @list.update(params). I ended up refactoring the whole Post request to be less complicated and much shorter.

Comment: I thought so but I didn't want to provide an answer in case it caused more problems, I shall be more bold in future! *Do* make sure to check that params hash before passing it on. [There are a few here](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=sinatra+parameter) (there's even one by me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
I found the answer to my own question.
I refactored my original post request to reflect this change:

```
post "/lists/:id" do
   @list = List.find(params[:id])
if @list.update(params)
  redirect "/lists/#{@list.id}"
else
  redirect "/lists/edit"
```

end
  end